Seeking Algorithm to Solve a Convolution Integral or Directly Convolve Two CDFs

Hi everyone,
I'm working on a project where I need to find a way to directly convolve two cumulative distribution functions (CDFs) given in polynomial form, and solve the following convolution integral:

    \[
    (F * G)(x) = \int F(x - y) \, dG(y)
    \]
    
Specifically, the functions I'm working with are:

    \[
    F(x) = 0.17 + \frac{0.83x}{150} \quad \text{for } 0 \leq x \leq 150
    \]
    

    \[
    G(y) = 0.25 + \frac{0.75y}{45} \quad \text{for } 0 \leq y \leq 45
    \]
    
For  x > 150 ,  F(x) = 1 , and for  y > 45 ,  G(y) = 1 , as these are cumulative distribution functions.
The real context of the problem is as follows: these CDFs describe the waiting time of a pedestrian at a traffic signal with the probability (cumulative) that they will wait, at most, that time. Therefore, the composition of both CDFs must necessarily include two points:

(x=0, y=0.0425): This point represents the situation where the pedestrian encounters both signals open, resulting in a cumulative probability of  0.17 x 0.25 = 0.0425 .
(x=195, y=1): This point represents the situation where the pedestrian encounters both signals closed at the moment they have just closed, resulting in a total waiting time of  150 + 45 = 195  seconds, with a cumulative probability of 1.

Does anyone know any algorithm that can accomplish this convolution, giving the answer in polynomial form? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I've tried looking into two posts - this one and this one - but neither offers a systematic method. One provides a formula with a function inside the differential  dG(y) , and I'm having difficulty understanding how this can be expanded, hence my search for a code alternative.
Thanks in advance for your help!

A couple of observations that may help point you in the direction of an answer:

The functions you have indicated don't seem to have the expected properties of CDF's. For example, as $x \rightarrow \infty$, $F\left(x\right)$ should approach $1.$  However, in the $F\left(x\right)$ above, clearly $F\left(x\right) \rightarrow \infty.$  Please see reference for additional details:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function

The usual convolution integral is given by:


$$
\left(F * G\right)\left(x\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F\left(x-y\right)G\left(y\right)\mathrm{d}y
$$
which doesn't appear to agree with the formulation you have provided.  It may be worth double checking to verify.  Here is a reference:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution
Assuming the standard definition, the integration would be
$$
\left(F*G\right)\left(x\right)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\left(0.17+\frac{0.83 \left(x-y\right)}{150}\right)\left(0.25+\frac{0.75 y}{45}\right) \mathrm{d}y
$$
which could be evaluated exactly using the usual rules of integration (multiplying out the terms, integrating term-by-term, and summing the results etc.).  However, please note that the functions in question don't seem to be correctly formulated CDF's to begin with as mentioned, so the result may not be as desired.

you're right. i didnt mention that for x>150, F(x) = 1 (and y>45) G(y) = 1, as I thought i'd be implicit by saying its a CDF. In this case, the solution would still be like yours', right? Thanks!

@guttf The solution is the correct definition.  If your CDF's are consistently defined (also going to zero appropriately etc, which I presume is at some finite value of $x$ like $x=0$ etc.) then applying that expression for the convolution integral should get you towards a solution.

txx! i just tried to apply it, and didnt work quite well. perhaps the convolution of two CDFs doesnt result on two CDFs (different from PDFs). just explained better the context on the main post - it doesnt make sense not having two points (0, 0.0425) and (195, 1)
